# Add meta information to photos?

Tags: camera, photos, gallery, editing, geotagging

Is there a decent camera app that will easily let me add a bit of text to my photos and store that text in the image file as EXIF/IPTC/XMP metadata? So far I have tried the stock Samsung camera app, Camera Zoom FX, Camera FV-5 and Catch Notes. I have read descriptions on numerous camera apps, but it seems like all they have to offer are various ways to distort - I mean enhance - your photos. While Catch Notes did offer ways to store your photos along with a description, it did not store the info as meta data inside the photo itself, which means it will be a mess if you ever want to transfer the photos to your computer and expect the data to stay intact.

This seems like a no-brainer that you'd expect to be available in almost every camera app. I mean, we've got the camera and the keyboard in the same device - what's the problem? I just want to be able to take a photo, click on an icon and type "This is a Bohemian Waxwing" and have that description stored inside the JPEG file. I'd even be fine with a gallery app that only let's me add information to already existing photos.

Comment: How about if you just rename the filename? That's what I usually do instead.

Comment: It's an alternative indeed, but as an absolute last resort. I'd much rather go for the metadata approach, this is after all what the EXIF information that's already in the JPEG's is for!

Comment: Stock Android photos app provides this feature since at least 7.1.1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a couple of apps in the Playstore which permit you to view/Edit EXIF data:

- <s>[Photo Image Editor - Photoshop](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.photo.imageeditor)</s> (free) says it can *View, edit, or delete EXIF data*
- Same promised by [Photo Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iudesk.android.photo.editor)
- <s>[Exif Editor and Viewer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.tequnique.exifeditor)</s> (paid) promises to *remove, modify, and add individual or multiple EXIF tags*
- <s>[Pixelgarde](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.pixelgarde.free)</s> even states: *Edit exif metadata for several photos as a batch, or just individual photos*

There are probably many more, so I just picked two of the more promising examples. And as Play Store is known for losing apps, please consider the above examples for the fact such apps exist – and check with [my list here](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/foto_edit#group_1044) for what is currently available.

Comment: Allright, answer accepted. [Photo Editor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.iudesk.android.photo.editor) is probably the best option. It's smooth enough when you use the camera apps' Share function > Photo Editor > Save (top right corner icon) > Modify > (enter text) > OK > Overwrite > Yes. Still, I cannot understand why this is not a standard feature in most camera apps, but I guess it's more fun to add a sepia effect than to write down what the photo actually is before you forget it.

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was posted, Android stock photos app now has a description field (Android 7.1.1). Open an image and click on the (i) icon, you will be able to add a description.

[image: screenshot showing description field]

Comment: Does that description end up in the Exif metadata somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend [SwiftTags](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=hu.imagetagger.tagging). It allows you to add EXIF keyword tags quite simply to your images, so later, you can use standard photo organizer software on your desktop to search your photos based on these tags. It focuses on simplicity, so you can assign your tags quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I am a owner of this app and suggest that you can use my app. This app called **ExifTool**, you can easily to change, add or delete metadata including Exif, XMP, IPTC, QuickTime or MarkerNote.

This app is ported to Android from [ExifTool by PhilHarvey](https://exiftool.org/).

Download this app (ExifTool), then click to Add Metadata.
That all info you needs.

[Download from Google Play](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.exiftool.free)

Answer (score -1):

Just installed Picscribe.  This allows you to add comments to exif data. Can't tell you if its a keeper app, as I have yet to abuse its power...! ;-)